# Name conflict with standard library

Tags: c++

My project uses a third party modules where one of the header file has defined 'errc'

```
typedef int             errc;
```

I want to use STL in project but when I add stl header file I get name conflict for errc since its class name in the standard library.

```
error C2872: 'errc' : ambiguous symbol
```

I don't really want to change the third party module, is there any way I can come around this problem and work with the standard library in the project?

Comment: Isn't `errc` part of `std`? That's what namespaces are for.

Comment: The only thing you should have to change is delete `using namespace std;` from your files.

Comment: yea but poor design/naming by third party module, they have used it which is outside my control

Comment: @Praetorian so I have to use fully qualified names than for stl objects!

Comment: @zadane, [That's a good thing.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-a-bad-practice-in-c) The using statements are scoped as well.

Comment: @zadane: the `std` namespace is there for a reason, and you just found out what that reason is. (You can use selective `using` statements to cut down on the typing.)

Comment: Zadane:  without changing anything else, try writing std::errc and ::errc in your program and see if that clears up the ambiguity.

Comment: I removed `using namespace std` and it compiles fine now.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use in the file

```
using namespace std;
```

But you can still include it into functions, say

```
void f()
{
  using namespace std;

  cout<<endl;
}
```